# Porque o meu vetor não está ficando ordenado?

Tags: c

Estou tentando criar um código, onde o mesmo ordena um **vetor** de `integer` por **questão de tamanho**, onde a **regra é a mesma do bubbleSort:**

- Irá comparar o valor da Esquerda com o da Direita
- Caso o valor da Esquerda for maior do que o da Direita, o valor da Direita deverá ir para a Esquerda e o valor da Esquerda para a Direita.

Exemplo:

```
int A[] = { 5, 1, 8, 4, 3, 10, 6, 2, 9, 7 };
```

Este vetor deverá ficar como:

```
int A[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
```

Segue meu código até o momento:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void bubbleSort(int v[], int tam) {
    for(int esquerda = 0; esquerda < tam-1; esquerda++) {
        for(int direita = esquerda+1; direita < tam; direita++) {
            if(v[esquerda] > v[direita+1]) {
                int aux = v[direita+1];
                v[direita+1] = v[esquerda];
                v[esquerda] = aux;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("ACABOU!\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        printf("%d", v[i]);
    }
}


int main()
{
    int A[] = { 5, 1, 8, 4, 3, 10, 6, 2, 9, 7 };
    bubbleSort(A, 10);

    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
ACABOU!
213456789
```

Comment: Faça dois loops. Um iterando entre cada item, o outro iterando do índice do primeiro + 1. O fim será quando o primeiro loop acabar.

Comment: Você tem que fazer uma varredura completa no vetor comparando cada elemento com o seguinte e, se houver uma troca, ligar a flag trocou. Note que você está desligando a flag a cada comparação e não apenas a cada ciclo. do { trocou = false; for (i=0; i<tam-1; i++) { /*verifica ordem*/} } while (trocou);

Comment: @anonimo eu vi o algoritmo do `BubbleSort`, porém ele utiliza um `while()` e dentro dele um `for()`, deixando o algoritmo `O(n²)`, é possível fazer o que estou tentando em `O(n)`? Onde ele faz a varredura completa, deixando todo vetor completamente ordenado ?

Comment: @KevinKouketsu esse será o fim, mas este fim talvez não quer dizer que o vetor esteja totalmente ordenado, não?

Comment: Eu não conheço nenhum algoritmo de ordenação que seja em média O(n). Os melhores que já vi são O(n log n). Mas faz um bom tempo que estudei este assunto.

Comment: @anonimo olha, alterei a questão.

Comment: Creio que seu loop com a variação de direita deva partir de esquerda+1 e não de 1 e deva ir até tam, e não tam-1.

Comment: @anonimo quase cara! O OUTPUT foi este: `213456789`

Comment: Nos índices da comparação e na troca não use direita + 1, use apenas direita.

Comment: @anonimo muito bom! Posta uma resposta sua com o meu código e a correção dele, explica também o que esta acontecendo para dar aquele erro e explica qual é o jeito correto para que as outras pessoas compreendam, irei assinar a sua pergunta como a correta, se puder me da uma pontuação também a na pergunta, pois não é algo trivial de certo modo.

Comment: @THIAGODEBONIS: na Wikipedia você encontra uma explicação detalhada de vários métodos de ordenação. Aliás li que existe um método que é O(n) mas que utiliza n processadores e exige n² de memória, o que certamente não funciona para aplicações normais.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Com os comentários [deste usuário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/106645/anonimo), consegui criar um código para o mesmo. Para os demais ficarem sabendo o funcionamento, segue o código:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void bubbleSort(int v[], int tam) {
    for(int esquerda = 0; esquerda < tam-1; esquerda++) {
        for(int direita = esquerda+1; direita < tam; direita++) {
            if(v[esquerda] > v[direita]) {
                int aux = v[direita];
                v[direita] = v[esquerda];
                v[esquerda] = aux;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("ACABOU!\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < tam-1; i++) {
        printf("%d", v[i]);
    }
}


int main()
{
    int A[] = { 5, 1, 8, 4, 3, 10, 6, 2, 9, 7 };
    bubbleSort(A, 10);

    return 0;
}
```